# I have a bot in telegram can I delete user's messages?

Tags: javascript, telegram, grammy

I am writing a bot on JS using grammy bibliothek I made a function createStickerPack everything works but I need to make it so that when the user sends sticker pack names after creating a sticker the user's messages are deleted how to do it ?

I have a sample code how to do it but it doesn't work, maybe there are people who can help me.

```js
bot.on('message', async (ctx) => {
  // console.log(ctx.message)
  if (ctx.message && ctx.message.text) {
    const userId = ctx.message.from.id;

    const sentMessage = await ctx.reply('Please wait...');

    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        // Delete the user's message
        await ctx.deleteMessage(sentMessage.chat.id, sentMessage.message_id);
        await ctx.deleteMessage(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.message_id); // Delete user message
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while deleting message:', error);
      }
    }, 5000); // Delete message after 5 seconds 2(in the example)
  }
});
```

```js
bot.on('message', async (ctx) => {
  // console.log(ctx.message)
  if (ctx.message && ctx.message.text) {
    const userId = ctx.message.from.id;

    const sentMessage = await ctx.reply('Please wait...');

    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        // Delete the user's message
        await ctx.deleteMessage(sentMessage.chat.id, sentMessage.message_id);
        await ctx.deleteMessage(ctx.message.chat.id, ctx.message.message_id); // Delete user message
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while deleting message:', error);
      }
    }, 5000); // Delete message after 5 seconds 2(in the example)
  }
});
```